# Getting error trying to load a sprite from a skin.json

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to load a simple skin in libgdx from a skin.json. The skin file is pretty simple:

```
{        
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite : {
            centerImage : {

            }
        }
}
```

Using this code, the code runs fine but I get an empty sprite. Tring to load a texture and load the sprite texturized, I get exception loading the texture:

```
{
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture : {
        centerImageTexture : {
            file : images/crop001.png
        }
    },

    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite : {
        centerImage : {
            texture : centerImageTexture
        }
    }
}
```

This is the libGDX code

```
 skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(skinFile));

centralImage = skin.getSprite("centerImage");
```

What I need is a way to define a texture into a skin file without the use of an atlas. The documentation explains how to load a texture:

```
Texture texture = skin.get("logo", Texture.class);
```

But I cannot find the way to define it

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you can find the cause easily via debug

Comment: I thinks I know what is happening. I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use

```
Texture texture = skin.get("logo", Texture.class);
```

the get-Method searches in **uiskin.atlas**, not the uiskin.json. There should be an entry named "logo":

```
logo
  rotate: false
  xy: 170, 44
  size: 100, 100
  orig: 100, 100
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

You can use this code snippet for your need. Modify for your needs are the parameters of **xy** (upper left corner of the TextureRegion in the uiskin.png and **size** and **origin** (size of your TextureRegion in Pixel). size and origin should be the same. The other parameters you can take as they are.